# Conditional RewriteBase - set base path only if localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set the base path for my localhost (but not for live). I have researched widely and this looked like a simple solution:

```
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '127.0.0.1'">
  RewriteBase /localpath/
  </If>
```

Unfortunately the RewriteBase statement NEVER fires - even if I make it != '127.0.0.1'.

I'm not sure if it is an issue with IF/RewriteBase combo, because if I put RewriteBase outside the  statement it does work.

Is there ANY WAY to test for LOCALHOST and then execute the Rewritebase command??

Comment: if condition works with apache 2.4 please confirm if that was the case.

Comment: Yes Apache 2.4.39 (wamp64)

Comment: Rewrite base seems to conflict with If blocks. For example `<If "true">RewriteBase /</If>` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You should be matching `%{SERVER_ADDR}` instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

```
<If "%{SERVER_ADDR} == '127.0.0.1'">
    RewriteBase /localpath/
</If>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anonymous's answer was helpful, but in my case HTTP_HOST worked better. Sharing in case it helps anyone else:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'myhostname'">  
RewriteBase /localpath/  
</If>
```